# Is it possible to use wildcards in API paths in IBM API Connect

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have a requirement to route all the API calls which meets some pattern, to a specific service. For example "/register/student", "register/teacher", "register/employee" should all go to one micro service. Can I define the above path (not absolute path for each API) using some wild card or pattern so that any request which matches the patter: "/register/**", should go to one specific micro service.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the path definition using path parameters and operation switches to control the flow of various patterns.

```
paths:
  'register/{myParam}':
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 OK
    parameters:
      - name: myParam
        type: string
        in: path
        required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a "**Base Path**" "**/resgister**" , then you can create the path "**strong text**/" asociated with some http method (get, post,...). Then in the you can usae javascript/gatewayscrip and some regex to filter $(request.path) and $(request.search) for your logic.

But if you whant to send all the request to some unique specific micro service, you only need to do the first part of the path and then use a "**Proxy**" politic.

Answer (score 0):

I find this discussion
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/discussion/wildcard-characters-in-path-parameters#bm99498f7b-a8a1-4a6e-875e-e01a4dd65d28

how point on the
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/10.0.1.x?topic=definition-defining-paths-api

And the example for 1 or more parameters is OK for me

```
  /read/{+params}:
get:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: 200 OK
parameters:
  - name: +params
    type: string        
    required: true
    in: path
```

But I can't find the good syntax for the 0 or more parameters

This example doesn't work but i would like to write some thing like  :

```
  /read/{*params}:
get:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: 200 OK
parameters:
  - name: *params
    type: string        
    in: path
```

But it doesn't work for me

If you have any Idea .....